# Inferring dto class members from keys of generic

Tags: typescript, entity, typeorm, typescript-generics, dto

I have an dto class of **QueryParams**, which I declare in the following way:

```
class QueryParams<T> {
  search?: string;

  page?: number;

  ...
}
```

What do I have to do inside **QueryParams** class to tell typescript that instead of explicitly declaring **search**, I want it to be a key of T?

For example, if I have

```
class AnotherEntity {
  prop_1: string
  prop_2: number
  prop_3: string
}

const query: QueryParamsDto<AnotherEntity>
```

I want to be able to do `query.prop_1` or `query.prop_2` or `query.prop_3` or `query.page`. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: I posted an answer for types, but if you need to do this with classes this gets weirder. Do you need these to be classes?

Comment: @AlexWayne yes, bc QueryParams is a class for a dto, and generic T is an entity

Answer (score 0):

You can make a type that simply makes all members of `T` optional, and intersects it with whatever additional properties you need.

```
type QueryParams<T> = Partial<T> & { page?: number }
```

And use it like so:

```
type AnotherEntity = {
  prop_1: string
  prop_2: number
  prop_3: string
}

declare const query: QueryParams<AnotherEntity>
query.prop_1 = 'abc' // fine
query.prop_2 = 123 // fine
query.prop_3 = 'def' // fine
query.prop_47 = 'prop_47' // type error
```

[See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.5&ssl=3&ssc=1&pln=13&pc=40#code/C4TwDgpgBAigrhATiACgQ0WgtgZwDwAqAfFALxTqLACWaANoSQGRQDeUYaA5hAPwBcUAHZwsAIyRQAvgCgZoSFACCQgPbAAFkgCiQmqDJsZUDolVgA+gEZBOYImpCux0+YsAmQSPFIXYM5YAzLb2js6yMgAmEADGdBjQMapCdlAAjgjIgvBIqBjY+CrqWoi6+iBEMhm5AHT+blaGAORoYjFNUAD0nVAAZo4QVZkgdQEehlbugV09-UKD1cijbtPkTdG9Hd19A0O19ZYALADszQcWJ1s9CtBIZohAA)